# Vue js passing HTML button name attribute as a PROPS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I created a custom component which contains an HTML button tag, so I'm using this component many times as a shared component into a parent component. I would like to know if I can pass the *name* attribute from the HTML button tag as a prop, so I can have a dynamically HTML button tag *name* attribute.

```
  <div class="toggle">
    <button
      class="btn"
      name="ships">
  </div>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    ships: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      default: ''
    }
  }
</script>


 <toggle
    :ships="white"
/>


 <toggle
    :ships="grey"
/>

 <toggle
    :ships="black"
/>
```

[CODE](https://codesandbox.io/s/6l5kjk5p53)

Comment: Have you got a JSFiddle setup you can share? We can edit this to help you.

Comment: @David.J just update code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle: https://codesandbox.io/s/00yxy5lqzn

Things I've changed:

**Toogle.vue**

```
<button class="btn" v-bind:name="ships">BUTTON </button>
```

To change an HTML attribute just add an `v-bind:` in front of it, because you can not use mustaches there.

**App.vue**

```
<div id="app">
  <toggle ships="black" />
  <toggle ships="grey" />
  <toggle ships="white"/>
</div>
```

Removed the double dot -> now the content of the property will be interpreted as an String.

Edit: Alternative you could do it this way (result is the same): `<toggle :ships="'black'" />` <-- it's probably the better way

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using a `prop` by using [`inheritAttrs`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs).

```
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
    name: "toggle",
};
```

And then use `$attrs` to access any fallthrough attributes e.g. `name`.

```
<div class="toggle">
    <button class="btn"
    v-bind:name="$attrs.name">BUTTON </button>
</div>
```

And then using your component would just be

```
<div id="app">
    <toggle name="black" />
    <toggle name="grey" />
    <toggle name="white"/>
</div>
```

Comment: On your toggle component definition.

Comment: ok, I see. Yes, it also works, probably It's a more elegant solution to use on HTML attributes rather than props

Comment: Yeah I use it when I have an element wrapping the actual element I want my attributes to be applied to.